# PHP Croogo Framework - Sites goes automatically to Maintenance Mode

Tags: php, mode, maintenance-mode, croogo

I am facing issue with Croogo website from last many days.  My site is going to maintenance mode automatically after few hours or few days.

Then i manually need to change **Site.status**: value to **1** in settings.yml

If anyone have any idea about this issue, Please share with me.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because settings.yml get refreshed by values from the database.
Try updating settings table accordingly:

```
update settings set `value` = '1' where `key` = 'Site.status';
```